# how to change a specific value in initial state object of a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**My reducer :**

The initial state is a object containing some strings. I need to update a single key alone.

```
export default function updatePersonDetailsReducer (state = {
    updatePersonDetails: {
        personName: "John",
        PersonId: "3hjbdfsjk33223",
        address: "somewhere on earth"
    }
}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case C.UPDATE_PERSON_DETAILS: {
            return {
                ...state
                ,updatePersonDetails :action.payload
            }
        }
        default : {}
    }
    return state
}
```

**Action :**

```
export function updatePersonDetails(data) {
  return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({
          type: C.UPDATE_PERSON_DETAILS,
          payload: data,
        });
  };
}
```

How do I change the personName alone from a component ?

Answer (score 1):

Spread your `updatePersonDetails` object as well :

```
export default function updatePersonDetailsReducer(state = {
  updatePersonDetails: {
    personName: "John",
    PersonId: "3hjbdfsjk33223",
    address: "somewhere on earth"
  }
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case C.UPDATE_PERSON_DETAILS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        updatePersonDetails: action.payload
      }
    }
    default: { }
  }
  return state
}
```

Action:

```
export function updatePersonDetails(data) {
  return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({
          type: C.UPDATE_PERSON_DETAILS,
          payload: {...data, personName: objValue.name},
        });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I change it in a componet ? like this,
`this.props.dispatch(updatePersonDetails(personName : objValue.name))` ?

Comment: I have updated the answer and added code for `dispatch` your `action`.

Comment: Great ! But one set back ! The personName is not only the one I have to change! So, in my reducer there is 3 values ( personName,personId,address ) which need to be changed in different component ( say, one component changes personName and another changes personId). Calling the action above would only change the personName. So, how do I change each one of it separately ?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the answer again and reverted this line in the `reducer`: `updatePersonDetails: action.payload`. So, now you can call the `updatePersonDetails` in your other components and just replace the `personName` property with whatever property you want to update

Comment: The action still got `personName: objValue.name` . So, if I still dispatch this from a component it would still only change the personName.

Comment: You need update this line: `payload: {...data, personName: objValue.name}` in other component and change the property that you want to update. Like: `payload: {...data, PersonId: objValue.id}`.

Comment: I suppose we can't change that in a action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234912/discussion-between-sai-krishnadas-and-shuvo).

Comment: changing to this in reducer will solve :  `return { updatePropertyDetails: {...state.updatePropertyDetails , propertyName:action.payload } }`